# Tanuki wrapper multiple unwanted instances

Tags: java, aix, jvm

Using Tanuki 3.5.25 software to manage a java8 service we encounter a problem on AIX that can be observed in the following logs:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 64-bit 3.5.25
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2014 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 64-bit 3.5.25
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2014 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 | Launching a JVM...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/08 15:07:09 | Launching a JVM...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:34 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
WARN   | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:37 | JVM exited unexpectedly while stopping the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:37 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:38 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:38 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 64-bit 3.5.25
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:38 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2014 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:38 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:38 |
STATUS | wrapper  | 2019/09/09 11:55:38 | Launching a JVM...
```

I have to mention that the JVM process is started by an external app that calls the wrapper script 2 times in a row.